# How to change the color of menu text?

Tags: 10.10, menu, themes, colors, text

I managed to change the selection color from orange to light gray which is very nice.

Now I'd like to change the text color of inactive/disabled menu items which are in black as you can see "Available" "Away" and "Busy", the text is black. I'd like it to be gray for example.

How to change the color of that text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change that property, you'll need to hack the `gtkrc` file for the theme in question. I presume that you're working with Ambiance.

The first thing you probably want to due is make a local copy of the theme instead of working on the system wide copy. Let's call it Ambiance-Mod. Open a terminal an run this:

`cp -r /usr/share/themes/Ambiance ~/.themes/Ambiance-Mod`

You also need to edit the `index.theme` to use your new theme.

`gedit ~/.themes/Ambiance-Mod/index.theme`

Change all instances on `Ambiance` to `Ambiance-Mod`

You should have Ambiance-Mod in your "Apperience Preferences." Now let's edit the `gtkrc` file.

`gedit ~/.themes/Ambiance-Mod/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

The the part that controls the text you'd like to change can be found on line 334, `fg[INSENSITIVE]` for `style "menu" = "dark"`

```
style "menu" = "dark" {
    xthickness = 0
    ythickness = 0

    bg[NORMAL] = "#43423f"
    bg[INSENSITIVE] = "#43423f"
    fg[INSENSITIVE]   = shade (0.54, "#43423f")

    engine "murrine"
    {
        roundness = 0
    }
}
```

You need to change `shade (0.54, "#43423f")` to use your desired Hex color. Try something like `"#969696"` Make sure it is quoted.

[image: change color]

If you're not afraid of messing up the original theme, you could edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` directly and skip the parts about copying the theme and renaming things in `index.theme`

If you'd like to play around with more options, check out [the GTK Theming Tutorial](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes) on the GNOME wiki.

Comment: A word of caution: If you go the local-theme route, your gksu applications (e.g synaptic) will look strange. They fall back to another theme because they can't use local themes. LP bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/24280