# How can I change the default color for all the text in the system manually

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization, gnome-panel

How can I change the overall default color for text of the whole system, be it for the GNOME panel,`tty`, shell, etc. Just the overall look and feel aspect of my system.

Comment: Almost a duplicate; here's the answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/7581

Comment: Well I have already have tried it but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to explain what exactly you have already tried? Also, mention what desktop environment is being used. The "everything of my system" also could be expanded: would you include web pages, pdf files, and spreadsheets in "everything"?

Comment: @Vreality, I'm not sure the question can be answered in its present form unless OP makes clear what is meant by "everything of my system". The link you provided dates back to 2010 when the gtk2/gtk3 "ratio" was different. Editing gtkrc affects only gtk2 apps. And the GNOME project is increasingly about gtk3.

Comment: @vasa1,Well is it good and okay now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To change the color on a tty you can use [`setterm`](http://tech-zilla.com/man_pages/ubuntu/1/setterm.html). Example:

   ```
   setterm -background black -foreground green
   ```

   If you want this when you log in you can add it to `.bashrc` otherwise you need to manually do this every time you log in to a tty.

   Colors:

   ```
   [grey||bright][black||red||green||yellow||blue||magenta||cyan||white]
   ```

   There are more options in the man page.

   edit: This will not work if you are already using another color scheme.
2. You might also be interested in color coding for directories ([dircolors](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dircolors.1.html)): [What do the different colors mean in ls?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/color-meanings-in-terminal)